# Generalizing quantum parallelism to bits or qubits

Tags: nielsen-and-chuang, quantum-parallelism

On pg. 31 in Nielsen and Chuang, it's said that:

> This procedure can easily be generalized to functions on an arbitrary number of **bits**, by
> using a general operation known as the Hadamard transform, or sometimes the Walsh–
> Hadamard transform

Aren't we trying to generalize to an arbitrary number of **qubits**? If it's bits, why isn't it qubits?

Comment: can you also add (in the post, not in the comments) what "procedure" is the text talking about?

Comment: I would guess that this means simply the following. To parallelize a boolean function of one bit you need one qubit+one ancilla (to store the result). To parallelize a function of n bits you would need $n$ qubits + one ancilla. So to me bits and qubits could be used interchangeably here.